# successfully paired bluetooth apple keyboard with Pi but can't type

Tags: pi-2, bluetooth, keyboard

I successfully followed all the instructions here http://www.adeepbite.com/apple-bluetooth-wireless-keyboard-trackpad-raspberry-pi/ to link a Bluetooth keyboard to a Pi with no errors and I still can't get input to the Pi when I press keys on the Bluetooth keyboard. Any suggestions as to why?

Thank you

(p.s. I've tried this with and without changing "KeyboardDisplay" to "DisplayYesNo" in /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent)

Comment: Please move your update as answering your own question. It keeps the flow of Q&A - Glad you got it working.

Comment: same issue discussing in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=257522&p=1719530#p1719530 and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=169274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later I got the keyboard and mouse working. I never had problems with the mouse but to get the keyboard working:

- I unpaired the keyboard with:

  bluez-test-device remove 00:12:A1:90:39:A9
- Then took out the batteries.
- Then redid the instructions and on the last 3 instructions I put yes after them instead of just the second to last (on accident but it worked).
- Also I was careful to ensure the keyboard was in discovery mode throughout the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of devices that might pair successfully, but do not function as intended. One device that comes to mind, is the Microsoft Universal Folding Keyboard that I use. It pairs fine to Linux deices, but it does not work as a keyboard despite the fact that it is presented as "universal". My advice would be to try different keyboards.