# Pairing an Apple wireless keyboard and mouse to Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian

Is it possible to pair an Apple wireless keyboard and mouse to Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [successfully paired bluetooth apple keyboard with Pi but can't type](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49961/successfully-paired-bluetooth-apple-keyboard-with-pi-but-cant-type)